# FirstPersonController collision functions not getting called

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, controller

if I add a OnCollisionStay or OnTriggerStay to my EnemyController of my Zombies, they dont Trigger my Player with Tag. My FPSController is tagged with "Player".

Here is the affected code of my EnemyController:

```
  private void OnCollisionStay(Collision collision)
{

    Debug.Log("Collision " + collision.gameObject.name);



    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player") {


        Debug.Log("TEST");



        if (Attack()) {

          collision.collider.SendMessageUpwards("PlayerDamage", damage, SendMessageOptions.RequireReceiver);

          Debug.Log("Player Damage");

        }

    }

}
```

The Debug.Log("TEST"); is not calling.

Here are the Inspector Settings from "FPSController" of my Player.

[image]

And Here my Enemy Inspector Settings:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about `OnCollisionEnter` ?

Comment: What happens when your zombies collide with another object? Lets say a cube. Can you try this? Add a cube and make your zombies have collision with it, with proper tag. I am asking this because of  **Character Controller**

Comment: The Problem is, that my Zombies are set to a Ragdoll and they always collide with its own Hips, arms, legs and so on... Every single part of their body have a capsule collider..

Comment: I want the zombies to hit my character as long as the collision stays...

Comment: I tried it with a cube - the zombies dont collide with the cube. They always collide with its own body parts - and i dont want that behaviour. Is it possible to deactivate Ragdoll behaviour?

Comment: You should be using `OnControllerColliderHit` to detect events when using Unity's `CharactetController` not  `OnCollisionXXX` or  `OnTriggerXXX` functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want two objects to collide with each other :

1. Both objects must have a `Collider`
2. At least one of the two objects must have a `Rigidbody` set to `non-Kinematic`
3. At least one of the two objects must have a script implementing `OnCollisionXXX` (this point is required only if you want to "capture" the collision messages)

Here, your player does not have a collider, so the collision won't be detected.

Source : https://unity3d.com/fr/learn/tutorials/topics/physics/colliders?playlist=17120

> Colliders are a component that allows the game object they're attached to react to other colliders provided that one of the game objects has a rigidbody component attached.
>
> Note that for an OnCollision message to be sent, one of the two objects colliding must have a rigidbody component.

Comment: OK!!!! Thank you so much :) I attached an Rigidbody to my Zombie and set it to non-kinematic! works!

Comment: Now I have another Problem... If i attach a Rigidbody to my enemys the collision is getting triggered but my zombies freakin out and turning around... on the other hand, when I set my Player to non-kinematic my Player freaks out... Is there another way?